send button in postman
I'm experiencing an issue with my Postman application. It seems that the 'Send' request button is missing from the interface. I'm trying to send a request, but I'm unable to do so because the button simply doesn't exist. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem?"


https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3951 This bugs mentions the disappearance of the Send-button when using a smaller window. It mentions it being fixed by implementing better zoom, but your size seems to small.

@Natrium
"I've attached a screenshot of my Postman interface, and it doesn't seem to be a zoom-related issue as mentioned in the bug report. My zoom level is normal, yet the Send button is still missing. Any other suggestions for resolving this problem?"

That's an example and not a request. If you use the bread crumb to go back one level, you'll find the request. You're also using an older version as the new version would have a Try button with leads to the request.

In the latest Postman user interface, there is a "comment mode" (conversation bubble icon) on the top right of the window. When you switch to this mode, the "Send" button will be missing:

If you switch back to "build mode" (pen icon), the "Send" button will be visible again:

Also, as @DannyDainton commented: if it is an example, the "Send" button is not supposed to be there.
